# Insert value of more than 32k chars into long column in oracle

Tags: database, oracle

I have a table with a column type of `LONG`. I know I could solve my problem by changing the column type to `CLOB` but I don't have that option in this case. I need to insert a value of more than 32k characters into this column.

Say i have a table called test with column named `c1` of type `LONG`.

The following statement will produce error.

```
insert into test(c1)values('string longer than 32k chars');
```

> error:ORA-01704: string literal too long.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Using tony's example from below I want to do something like the following:

```
declare
   x varchar2(40000) := rpad('x',40000,'x');
begin
   insert into test (c1) values (x);
end;
```

I know you can't make varchar(2) that big but i want to exercise the idea.

Comment: Has it already been 20 years since LONGs were deprecated? Somebody really dropped the ball if you're still stuck with them in your database.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with SQL.  You'd be looking at writing an external client most likely in C that could use the old OCI API to insert that much data into a LONG.

Comment: Maybe use this as a good reason to update LONG to CLOB?

Comment: Agreed unfortunately not an option in this case

Answer (score 1):

You can insert 32K characters from PL/SQL:

```
declare
   x varchar2(32767) := rpad('x',32767,'x');
begin
   insert into test (c1) values (x);
end;
```

Comment: In your above example where would the 4000 character string go?

Comment: In the example above, `rpad('x', 32767, 'x')` is a character string of length 32767, where all the characters are `x`. It is created, and then assigned to the VARIABLE x (which is created and assigned a value at the same time). Then it is inserted into table `test`, in column `c1`

Comment: so when i replace "rpad('x',32767,'x')" with '[string longer than 4000]' i get the error. Your example works. I don't understand why replacing rpad('x',32767,'x') would not work.

Comment: And in this case looks like strings can be greater than 32k

Comment: Can you post (a simplified version if necessary) of the actual code that is failing when you use my method?

Comment: So i was mistaken. Your code works fine as long as string is less than 32k. It only fails when string greater than 32k